# Scala: Compare Arrays ignoring order

Tags: arrays, scala, equality

I was wondering if there's any method within Arrays that checks for equality ignoring order. By far, I did find this one:

```
  test("test ignoring order"){
    assert(Array(1,2,4,5).sameElements(Array(1,4,2,5)))
  }
```

But it fails as the order is not the same:

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: scala.Predef.intArrayOps(scala.Array.apply(1, 2, 4, 5)).sameElements[Int](scala.Predef.wrapIntArray(scala.Array.apply(1, 4, 2, 5))) was false
```

Is there any method to do this, inside or outside *Arrays*?

EDIT: I don't need to sort the arrays, I just want to compare them ignoring order.

Comment: Try with `Array(1,2,4,5) contain theSameElementsAs Array(1,2,4,5)` if you are using **Scalatest**, also I would recommend you to do not use **Arrays** but rather a real collection like **List** or **Vector**. - Finally, you may also `sort` them, or convert them into **Sets** _(if you do not care about the number of times each element is present)_ or use `groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)` on both to compare two occurrences maps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I don't want to sort them, and I need to use the array. How can I import Scalatest? Could you please place a Unit test example like mine in the question? (Never used ScalaTest)

Comment: Which test framework are you using? Why do you need **Arrays**? Why you do not want to sort them or any other of the alternatives? _(note that any method that does such comparison is doing something similar under the hood)_

Comment: I'm using FunSuite as framework

Comment: **FunSuite** is not a framework, **FunSuite** is one of the classes of [**Scaltest**](https://www.scalatest.org/) . It may be good for you to first learn more and understand what you are using.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez from Scala's official documentation: "ScalaTest framework called FunSuite." (source: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/testing-scala-in-intellij-with-scalatest.html). It may be good for you to first double check what you think you know ;)

Comment: Didn't check it, undone

Comment: _"There are multiple libraries and testing methodologies for Scala, but in this tutorial, we’ll demonstrate one popular option from the ScalaTest framework called FunSuite"_ if you are also a non native English speaker like me, I know it may be confusing sometimes. However, this is pretty clear, the article is using an _"option"_ (which being honest is a bad word in this context) from the **ScalaTest** framework (so you are using the **ScalaTest** framework as I mentioned in my first comment, just check the docs on how to use `Marchers`), and such option is the `FunSuite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursion will do it.

```
def isSame[T](arrA:Array[T], arrB:Array[T]) :Boolean =
  arrA.length == arrB.length &&
    (arrA.isEmpty || isSame(arrA.filterNot(_ == arrA.head)
                           ,arrB.filterNot(_ == arrA.head)))
```

But @Tim's question is valid: What's your objection to the obvious and simple sorted solution?

Comment: Nice. Could avoid the bare `head` with `arrA.length == arrB.length && arrA.headOption.forall(x => isSame(arrA.filterNot(_ == x), arrB.filterNot(_ == x)))`

Comment: @Tim; I like it. We loose the tail-recursion but that's a small matter.

Comment: Good point about tail recursion. In the end it depends on what is the motivation for this is, which remains unclear.

Answer (score 3):

It's an older thread, but I just had the same question.

The proposed answers include sorting (which only works for comparable objects) or approaches with O(n^2) runtime behavior (and/or non-trivial recursion).

Another (simple yet understandable and powerful) approach would be to use Scala's diff function:

```
def hasSameElementsUnordered[T](arrA: Array[T], arrB: Array[T]): Boolean = {
    (arrA.length == arrB.length) && (arrA diff arrB).isEmpty
}
```

BTW this works on any collection and element types, not only arrays and comparables.
Internally diff() builds an occurrence count hash map, so runtime behavior will be much better for larger collections.

Answer (score 1):

Following will sort both the arrays and then equates them :

```scala
test("test ignoring order"){
  assert(Array(1,2,4,5).sorted sameElements Array(1,4,2,5).sorted)
}
```

NOTEs:

1. You can use `==` instead of `sameElements` if you are working with some other collections apart from `Array`.
2. `array1.toSet == array2.toSet` won't work if one of the array has duplicates while other doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I would like to compare them ignoring order, without sorting them

Comment: @dev What is the problem with sorting them? This is a test not mainline code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this working as expected ??

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def equalsIgnoringOrder(first:Array[Int], second:Array[Int]) : Boolean = {

  def removeAtIndex(i:Int, array: Array[Int]) : Array[Int] = {
    val buffer = array.toBuffer
    buffer.remove(i)
    buffer.toArray
  }

  @tailrec
  def firstEqualSecondRec(i:Int, other:Array[Int]) : Boolean = {
    if(other.isEmpty) true
    else {
      val el = first(i)
      val index = other.indexOf(el)
      if(index == -1) false
      else firstEqualSecondRec(i+1, removeAtIndex(index, other))
    }
  }

  if (first.length != second.length) false
  else {
    val startingIndex = 0
    firstEqualSecondRec(startingIndex, second)
  }
}
```